# EventGridTrigger Azure Function - How to return bad request to immediately deadletter

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Event Grid triggered function. I read the documentation and saw that if you return a bad request, the event will be dead-lettered immediately (if dead-lettering is setup) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#failure-codes

If I want to immediately deadletter, is it simply a case of returning a `HttpResponseMessage` with `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` or similar?

i.e:

```
[FunctionName("EventGridFunction")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *EventGridTrigger* Exception to force the *HttpStatusCode.BadRequest*. 
It will be nice to have it, but a current version of the *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid* doesn't handling this feature.

However, the workaround for this case is to use a *HttpTrigger* function with handling a validation response code or calling a Get validation url. In this trigger you can handle a HttpResponseMessage.

Note, there is a built-in (no configurable) ~300 seconds delay when the dead-letter will show up in the blob storage.