# Azure Event Grid Trigger Function retry on 500

Tags: azure, function, event-handling, azure-eventgrid

I have created Azure Function of type EventGridTrigger as subscriber to a topic in Event Grid. This function calls the downstream api using rest client.

However there could be scenarios where downstream api is not avaialble or there is exceptions while calling downstream api from EventGridLtrigger. In such case I have observed EventGridTopic is still showing Event as delivered instead of retrying on failure.

Is there anyway possible to get EventGrid to retry delivery or possibly add the event in deadletter queue when there is processing failures?

Comment: have a look at my answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302054/eventgridtrigger-azure-function-how-to-return-bad-request-to-immediately-deadl

Answer (score 2):

- `Eventgrid` will retry if and only if the failure is not because of a
  configuration error which intrinsically cannot be solved by the retry.
- You can configure retry policy by configuring two variables                                `Max ammount of retry` and `event time to live`. As their name suggest
  maximum attempts which can be made before either droping the message
  or dead lettering it, event time to live will configure the time
  between each retry by default it is 1440.

You can configure retry policy when you create the event grid.

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create \ 
-g gridResourceGroup \ 
--topic-name  <topic_name> \ 
--name  <event_subscription_name> \ 
--endpoint  <endpoint_URL> \
 --event-ttl  720\
 --max-delivery-attempts  18
```

**Reference:**

[Retry in event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry)

Comment: In my case event is delivered to EventGridTrigger subscriber function and then due to code error 500 exception was thrown but EventGrid didn't try retry but it was showing it is as Delivered Event even though I have configured retry policy as per Microsoft's document

Answer (score 0):

If there is internal server error (status code 500) in the Azure EventGrid Trigger function, Event Grid will retry delivery based on the configuration. Use below link for more details.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/issues/32